# Can't use electron's webview attributes in React component

Tags: reactjs, electron

Given an electron-webview like

```
<webview
  minwidth="300"
  minheight="300"
  src="http://www.javascript-coder.com/files/window-popup/javascript-window-open-example1.html"
  allowpopups
></webview>
```

Using directly in `app.html` it works as expected.

But when I use it inside a react-component or just ReactDom.render, it omits all props except `src`. So the popup don't open on click:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

render(
  <webview
    minwidth="300"
    minheight="300"
    src="http://www.javascript-coder.com/files/window-popup/javascript-window-open-example1.html"
    allowpopups
  />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

In the devtools I get

> Warning: Unknown props `minwidth`, `minheight`, `allowpopups` on
>    tag. Remove these props from the element. For details, see
>   https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/unknown-prop.html

hint: I use the latest https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add your component class code for the webview?

Comment: I added a small example

Comment: can you try `minWidth` and `minHeight` on the component? Notice the camelCase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the `webview` element in a React component, and have the component create and insert the element into the DOM in `componentDidMount()`. See [this issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/6046) for more details.